# MySQL: JOIN with empty tables and COUNT(*) returns a row with 0 COUNT, but adding a GROUP BY on a constant value returns nothing?

Tags: mysql

Can someone explain why, when these tables are empty, the following query returns a COUNT(*) of 0 and a MAX(Timsestamp) of null...

```
SELECT 'Combined', COUNT(*), MAX(Timestamp)
FROM TableA 
JOIN TableB USING (Id)
```

...while adding a simple "GROUP BY" on the constant value (first column) returns no rows at all?

```
SELECT 'Combined', COUNT(*), MAX(Timestamp)
FROM TableA
JOIN TableB USING (Id)
GROUP BY 1
```

I wasn't able to find anything in the MySQL documentation explaining this behavior.